# Drupal location CCK field does not save

Tags: drupal, location, field, cck, save

I have installed Location, GMAP, GMAP Location and Location CCK modules.

I needed Location CCK because I could not force ordinary location to show in specific field group. It looks like it is attached statically to the main group (I have defined field groups as a tabs and do not want to show location information on the main tab).
After installing Location CCK and adding Location CCK field to it the field values are not being saved.
Other symptom is that when editing node, location CCK does not pick up default values from location settings (like default country or default map picker position). So it looks like my Location CCk do not save and read to/from locations properly.

I am using: 
Drupal 6.19,
Location CCK 6.x-3.1, 
Location 6.x-3.1, 
GMap Location 6.x-1.1, 
GMap 6.x-1.1

Anyone met that issue?

I would be very grateful for hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable "Node Locations" and "Location Add Another" module. They're conflict with "Location CCK".

And if it doesn't help, search in the issue queues of the modules you are using. 90% of the time people you will find someone has report the same issue than yours. http://drupal.org/project/issues/location?status=All&categories=All

Comment: Thank You. It helped! There is one think to remember - it needs also to remove and resave all the locations again.